# Why isn't the first value entered taken into account?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

If the first number entered is the maximum or the minimum of all numbers entered, the program doesn't take that value as the minimum or maximum. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a set of integers: ");
    System.out.println("When done entering, enter a non integer (e.g. a floating-point number or string).");


    int smallest = in.nextInt();
    int largest = in.nextInt();

    while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if (input > largest) {
            largest = input;
        }
        else {  
        }
        if (input < smallest) { //doesn't include first input?
            smallest = input;
        }   
        else {  
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Maximum: " + largest);
    System.out.print("Minimum: " + smallest);
    in.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you entering for each call to `nextInt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have optimized your code a bit. You were checking for nextDouble but you had the loop go on if it evaluated to true and the reason the program stops is because an exception was being thrown. Besides that in your system out you say it could be a string as well. You also decided that the first input would be the smallest and the second the largest. That may lead to interesting problems (if I enter 10, 1, 5.5 in that order it will tell me the smallest is 10 and the largest 1). The code I've written still fails to no integers being entered but you haven't specified expected behavior for that case.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a set of integers: ");
        System.out.println("When done entering, enter a non integer (e.g. a floating-point number or string).");

        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int input = in.nextInt();
            if (input > largest) {
                largest = input;
            }
            if (input < smallest) {
                smallest = input;
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + smallest);
        in.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, I indeed made a mistake with the nextDouble! I tried initialize my smallest and largest with Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE, but then when I input my numbers and press a non integer when done entering, I get an overflow.

Comment: @GwenLS hmm I'm going to need a little bit more information. Can you please add the exact stacktrace and input you gave my code. I just tried `3 1 235 3 612 3 2 -235 23 5 1 -6 asd` and it worked.

Comment: It is working now! I accidentally switched Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE. @InsertKnowledge

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 bugs

1. you are not comparing smallest and largest, maybe smallest is bigger than largest, remember you get first 2 inputs already one by one.
2. You checking in while with nextDouble but using getInt for integer.

Comment: Thank you, I indeed made a mistake with nextDouble!

Comment: @GwenLS so feel free to ask question if you still have error or mark answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: if the first input is the largest, it still doesn't work, because the max printed out is the second max number of user input. If the first input is the smallest it does work though.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the Scanner for "hasNextDouble" and then you try to pull out an int (nextInt), which will always throw.
Here's a quick solution (still without any validation of the first two inputs...)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a set of integers: ");
System.out.println("When done entering, enter a non integer (e.g. a floating-point number or string).");


int smallest = in.nextInt();
int largest = in.nextInt();
if (smallest > largest) {
    int tmp = smallest;
    smallest = largest;
    largest = tmp;
}

while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if (input > largest) {
            largest = input;
        } else if (input < smallest) {
            smallest = input;
        }
    }
    if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Maximum: " + largest);
System.out.println("Minimum: " + smallest);
in.close();
```